# how to do onclick hide and show in angular using service.ts?

Tags: typescript, angular8

In my project, I have a two components like content and view. I am using service.ts for connecting (extend) these two components. in content component I have a method. when I call that method one div will show in view component. both are interacting using service.ts.
I tried boolean method but it's not working.

content component:

```
 <button (click)="filterService.filterClicked()"
        [class.active]="filterService.filterChanged"
        id="filterDropdown" type="button"
        class="dropdown-toggle btn btn-clear-default job-filter">
        <i class="fa fa-funnel-thin mr-10"></i>
 </button>
```

content component ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {
  constructor(
    public filterService: FilterService) {

  }
}
```

service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
  @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
 })
 export class FilterService {
   public filterShow: boolean;

   filterClicked(){
      this.filterShow = !this.filterShow;
   }}
```

view component:

```
<div *ngIf= "filterService.filterShow">
  content
</div>
```

view component ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterService } from "../../services/filter.service";
@Component({
  selector: 'jobs-sub-header',
  templateUrl: './sub-header.component.html',
   providers:  [ FilterService ]
})
export class SubHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(
   private filterService: FilterService) {
 }
```

if anyone knows please share it here. I tried but it is not working.

Comment: try to change filterService to public in SubHeaderComponent constructor

Comment: yeah... tried but nothing works.

Comment: can you provide sample project on https://stackblitz.com/ for testing ?

Comment: @NajiMakhoul i tried samething in this url- https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvwcz8?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html .  but in stackblitz its working fine. but for me its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Some things.

1. I think you pasted the wrong code in content component ts:
2. If you use

   @Injectable({     providedIn: 'root' })

then you don't need

```
selector: 'jobs-sub-header', 
templateUrl: './sub-header.component.html', 
providers:  [ FilterService ]  <-----------
```

providedIn:'root' means that this service will be available to all caompnents from the root on up.

3. I can't see where you've defined filterShow

   ```
   import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
   @Injectable({
       providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class FilterService {

    filterShow:boolean = false <----------

    filterClicked(){
        this.filterShow = !this.filterShow;
    }
   }
   ```

I think I see what your trying to do now. Behaviour subject from rxjs is probably what you need.

Here's a sample

New Service:

```
 import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'
 import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
 @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
 })
export class FilterService {
   public filterShow: boolean = false

//----------------------------------------------------------------//

private _source = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)
show$ = this._source.asObservable()

//----------------------------------------------------------------//

click(): void {
    this.filterShow = !this.filterShow;
    this._source.next(this.filterShow)
}//click

//----------------------------------------------------------------//

}
```

To use it.
Import it in Content and subContent like you already did
then to use it in your html use this:

```
Content <h3 *ngIf="filterService.show$ | async">Show</h3>
```

these lines in the service

```
private _source = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false)
show$ = this._source.asObservable()
```

means that the same value for show will be available to all compoents using it and the value will be emitted everytime it's changed (from anywhere)

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7grjub

Comment: thank for your support. iam saying this method-filterClicked();

Comment: check the code you've entered for content-component.ts

Comment: I am saying  this method - filterClicked(){
     this.filterShow = !this.filterShow;
 } filtershow content should hide and show based on method.

Comment: default filterShow content hide. when i call the method that time it should visible. i think now you got that point.

Comment: That method would be fine if you've actually defined filterShow. I can't see where you did.

Comment: can you check my question i mention it -<div *ngIf= "filterService.filterShow">
  content
</div>

Comment: You put the correct content-component.ts up. You've entered the code for FilterService twice. So I can't see what's going on there.

Comment: You still need to DEFINE the variable filterShow. YOu have to tell the computer that there is a public variable called filterShow in FilterService. i.e. add the line : filterShow: boolean to your FilterService

Comment: now you can able to see the complete code in my question?

Comment: this is content-component.code -import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
  @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FilterService {
  constructor(
    public filterService: FilterService) {

  }
}

Comment: here's a stackblitz : with BehaviourSubject in action https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7grjub

Comment: thank you so much @shanie...but for you it's working but for me, it's not working. content component it's working fine.. but in the view component, it's not changing.. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Put tout code on stack blitz so I can see it in action.